# How to parse seq of words separated by double spaces using fparsec?

Tags: parsing, f#, fparsec

Given the input:

```
alpha beta gamma  one two three
```

How could I parse this into the below?

```
[["alpha"; "beta"; "gamma"]; ["one"; "two"; "three"]]
```

I can write this when there is a better separator (e.g.__), as then

```
sepBy (sepBy word (pchar ' ')) (pstring "__")
```

works, but in the case of double space, the pchar in the first sepBy consumes the first space and then the parser fails.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The FParsec manual [says](http://www.quanttec.com/fparsec/reference/primitives.html#members.sepBy) that in `sepBy p sep`, if `sep` succeds and the subsequent `p` fails (without changing the state), the entire `sepBy` fails, too. Hence, your goal is:

1. to make the separator **fail** if it encounters more than a single space char;
2. to **backtrack** so that the "inner" `sepBy` loop closed happily and passed control to the "outer" `sepBy` loop.

Here's how to do the both:

```fsharp
// this is your word parser; it can be different of course,
// I just made it as simple as possible;
let pWord = many1Satisfy isAsciiLetter

// this is the Inner separator to separate individual words
let pSepInner =
    pchar ' '
    .>> notFollowedBy (pchar ' ') // guard rule to prevent 2nd space
    |> attempt                    // a wrapper that fails NON-fatally

// this is the Outer separator
let pSepOuter =
    pchar ' '
    |> many1                      // loop over 1+ spaces

// this is the parser that would return String list list
let pMain =
    pWord
    |> sepBy <| pSepInner         // the Inner loop
    |> sepBy <| pSepOuter         // the Outer loop
```

Use:

```fsharp
run pMain "alpha beta gamma  one two three"
Success: [["alpha"; "beta"; "gamma"]; ["one"; "two"; "three"]]
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend replacing `sepBy word (pchar ' ')` with something like this:

```
let pOneSpace = pchar ' ' .>> notFollowedBy (pchar ' ')
let pTwoSpaces = pstring "  "
// Or if two spaces are allowed as separators but *not* three spaces...
let pTwoSpaces = pstring "  " .>> notFollowedBy (pchar ' ')
sepBy (sepBy word pOneSpace) pTwoSpaces
```

Note: not tested (since I don't have time at the moment), just typed into answer box. So test it in case I made a mistake somewhere.

Comment: I think this one needs the attempt used above, else you get an error.